# Hiding Virtual Keyboard

Tags: android

I am using the below code to hide virtual keyboard when i hit Enter key, but its not hiding. If anybody know about this or any mistake in code please reply me.

```
package onchip.learning.smalltest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class SmallTest extends Activity {
    EditText et;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        et = new EditText(this);
        et.setLines(1);
        et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setContentView(et);

        et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Are you testing this on emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0)` instead of `hideSoftInputFromInputMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```